# openerp: how to stop calling an action directly from url?

Tags: odoo

The user can call any action out of his scope by writing action code directly in url. This makes a big hole in security of odoo.

BR

Comment: What is the question again?

Comment: suppose you have a menu that calls an action and that action opens a view. When you press the menu a url will be created that will open that view. I can add groups="some rule" to menu and hide it for given rule. but if you save that url or some how hack the action number of that view you can simply write that url and you are in. That is the problem.

Comment: It's best to edit your question to improve it.

Comment: I create this module based on the above idea and it works. Naive but works.
https://github.com/mehdisam/ActionGroup.git